# Return creates empty record on database on Cakephp 1.3

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a very strange issue and I can't find any fix for it.
I have the following code:

```
function convertToComponent($idPryComponent) {
    $pryComponentData = $this->{$this->modelClass}->findByIdPryComponent ( $idPryComponent );
    $this->loadModel ('ComponentSource' );

    if ($this->ComponentSource->save ( $pryComponentData [$this->modelClass] )) {
        $idComponent = $this->ComponentSource->id;
        $pryComponentData [$this->modelClass] ['ID_COMPONENT'] = $idComponent;
        $save=array();
        $save['PryComponent']['ID_PRY_COMPONENT']=$idPryComponent;
        $save['PryComponent']['ID_COMPONENT']=$idComponent;
        $return= $this->PryComponent->save ($save);
        return  $idComponent;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

And after the save actiond, the sentence "return  $idComponent;", inserts another empty record on the database, and I don't know why!!!
Could you help?

Comment: Have you inspected `$pryComponentData [$this->modelClass]`?

Comment: Hi! Yes, but the problem is that after the save action, after the return it inserts another record but this time empty (just with a new id an nothing else)

Comment: Do you mean `$this->PryComponent->save()` saves another record in cascade? How have you defined the relationship between models?

Comment: IT's on the return sentence when it inserts another record. I inspected the database after the save, and only one record was inserted, but when the debug reaches return  $idComponent; it inserts an empty record